# How to change products in hot sellers list Luma theme (RESOLVED)

Tags: magento2, widget

I found code hot sellers widget in cms block,

> {{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_per_page="5" products_count="5" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:3:`sku`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`()`;s:5:`value`;s:60:`WS12, WT09, MT07, MH07, 24-MB02, 24-WB04, 241-MB08, 240-LV05`;]]"}}

But i got error when replace a product have sku `WS12 by WSH12`.

> {{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_per_page="5" products_count="5" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:3:`sku`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`()`;s:5:`value`;s:60:`WSH12, WT09, MT07, MH07, 24-MB02, 24-WB04, 241-MB08, 240-LV05`;]]"}}

```
Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset magento widget
```

I don't know how to add or replace products in widget right way.

**Update**

After struggle with this issue i resolved it by my self. I wrote script create conditions_encode by using class Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions; It has encode function.

Using encode value and replace conditions_encoded products will update.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$cons= array(
    "1"=>array(
        "type"=>'Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine',
        "aggregator"=>'all',
        "value"=>'1',
        "new_child"=>'',
    ),
    "1--1"=>array(
        'type'=>'Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product',
        'attribute'=>'sku',
        'operator'=>'()',
        'value'=>'crowe-sweater,Easy Full Dress,Herve Leger,Striped Maxi Dress,Daisy Lace Trim Blouse',
    )
);
$a=new Conditions();
$s=$a->encode($cons);
echo "<pre>";
echo($s);
echo "</pre>";exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have check this issue. You have to added new widget for update
>   products and remove old one, else you need to check that condition
>   that added when widget was created and need to follow this condition.
>   There is no any way to edit that catalog list widget which is added in
>   static block directly.

Comment: I've just updated right way to do it. Thanks